# How do I stop when the sentence is invalid? It still writes the number of characters

Tags: c#

```
 // If statement, User input is executed
 if (userInput == "k")
 {
   // User enters their statement
   Console.WriteLine("Enter your statement");
   myScen = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
```

Code for full stop

```
   // Does the sentence end with a full stop?
   if (myScen.EndsWith("."))
      Console.WriteLine("\n\tSentence Ended Correctly");

   else
      Console.WriteLine("Invalid Sentence");
```

Need a stop command here. This is where it does not stop and continues to calculate the numbers

```
   // Calculate number of characters
   foreach (char c in myScen)
   {
      numbChar++;
      if (c == ' ')
         continue;

      newScen += c;
   }
   Console.WriteLine("\n\tThere are {0} characters. \n\n\n",numbChar);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me try:

```
if (myScen.EndsWith("."))
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n\tScentence Ended Correctly");
    // Calculate number of characters
    foreach (char c in myScen)
    {
        numbChar++;
        if (c == ' ')
            continue;

        newScen += c;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\n\tThere are {0} characters. \n\n\n",numbChar);
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Scentence");
```

So, just calculate the number of characters only if your sentence is valid. Otherwise only print a message.

Comment: *offtopic:* with LINQ, the character count can be computed more succintly: `numbChar = newScen.Count(c => c != ' ')`

Comment: @w0lf really *offtopic*, as the OP is only learning to use the `if` statement...surely it's a little bit early to speak about LINQ. Besides he counts all characters, and concats in `newScen` those `!= ' '`...So, the suggested LINQ works differently...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert result of `Console.ReadLine()` call to string, because it is already string.

```
if (userInput == "k")
{
   Console.WriteLine("Enter your statment");
   myScen = Console.ReadLine();

   if (myScen.EndsWith(".")) 
   { // use block of code here
       Console.WriteLine("\n\tScentence Ended Correctly");
       // Calculate number of characters...
   }
   else
       Console.WriteLine("Invalid Scentence");       
}
```

Also you can calculate non-whitespace characters this way `mySen.Replace(" ", "").Length`